# access elements inside webbrowser tool

Tags: c#

I am working on a windows form application, and I was wondering how to access elements inside the webbrowser. Say for example there is an element like this `<button class="btn btn_Roll">Roll Dice</button>` how do I get that elemenet and perdorm a click action?

I know you can acccess elements by id like so

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement example = document.GetElementById("some_id_here");
```

How is it done with class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
var element = this.objWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button").
                  Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(e => 
                                            e.GetAttribute("class")).
                                            FirstOrDefault();

if(element == null) return;

element.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: how do i first get a hold of the element if it only has a class attribute?